# Grouping table columns having duplicates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, aggregate-functions

Am trying to group the information from a table called 'fruit_tb' below where the columns, 'cat_item' and 'ng_value' fall under their respective column 'ng_fy'; Below is the extracted table from MySQL.

| cat_item | ng_fy | ng_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 2019/20 | 5 |
| Mangoes | 2019/20 | 14 |
| Oranges | 2019/20 | 3 |
| Pears | 2019/20 | 2 |
| Apples | 2020/21 | 11 |
| Mangoes | 2020/21 | 4 |
| Oranges | 2020/21 | 13 |
| Pears | 2020/21 | 0 |
| Apples | 2022/23 | 1 |
| Mangoes | 2022/23 | 4 |
| Oranges | 2022/23 | 18 |
| Pears | 2022/23 | 21 |

Below is the output am trying to achieve which will be in json format and such that i can render it on a bar graph (using chartjs).

```
2019/20 => [
    ["cat_item" => Apples,
    "ng_value" => 5],
    ["cat_item" => Mangoes,
    "ng_value" => 14],
    ["cat_item" => Oranges,
    "ng_value" => 3],
    ["cat_item" => Pears,
    "ng_value" => 2],
],
2020/21 => [
    ["cat_item" => Apples,
    "ng_value" => 11],
    ["cat_item" => Mangoes,
    "ng_value" => 4],
    ["cat_item" => Oranges,
    "ng_value" => 13],
    ["cat_item" => Pears,
    "ng_value" => 0],
],
2021/23 => [
    ["cat_item" => Apples,
    "ng_value" => 1],
    ["cat_item" => Mangoes,
    "ng_value" => 4],
    ["cat_item" => Oranges,
    "ng_value" => 18],
    ["cat_item" => Pears,
    "ng_value" => 21],
]
```

This is the query am using:

```
$query = "SELECT ng_fy, cat_item, ng_value FROM fruit_tb GROUP BY ng_fy, cat_item ORDER BY ng_fy ASC";
```

I then loop through the information using PHP. Except am not getting the desired results. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL offers JSON builder and aggregate functions that come handy here:

```
select ng_fy, 
    json_arrayagg(
        json_object(
            'cat_item', cat_item,
            'ng_value', ng_value
        )
    ) js  
from fruit_tb
group by ng_fy
order by ng_fy
```

Here, `json_object()` builds json objects that `json_arrayagg()` then aggregates. This returns a resultset with two columns, one that holds the date and the other the json array.